# Is it possible to restrict the WinForms DateTime Picker dropdown to only choose the month and year?

Tags: winforms, c#-4.0, datetimepicker

I want to use the WinForms DateTime Picker to force user input specifically to the MM/YYYY format when entering expiration dates for credit cards.

In the DateTimePicker I've found the CustomFormat option and set it to MM/yyyy and the Format option and set it to custom, which works well enough in that only the month and the year are getting displayed. Now I need to know how to either completely hide and disable the drop-down arrow, or make it so that when a user clicks it they can only select the month and the year from it (not the day).

Is this possible in WinForms? I would be happy to completely disable the dropdown calendar if that's possible and if it's the only option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the property of the datetime picker's "Format" to Custom, then change the CustomFormat to MM/yyyy

edit:
then set the `ShowUpDown` property to true

Comment: I did that. It did not change the dropdown on the calendar. The days still appear. I also explicitly mentioned that I did that in the question.

Comment: you can set the ShowUpDown property to true

Comment: showupdown does not effect the dropdown. it's already set to false. that's not about what I am speaking.
EDIT: Actually setting it to true kind of backwards handled it for me. Setting to true hides the dropdown and resolves the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dateTimePicker1.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;
        dateTimePicker1.CustomFormat = "MMMM yyyy";
        dateTimePicker1.ShowUpDown = true;
    }
```

This is how it looks like when you run the application.

[image]

When you click on the DateTimePicker it will no longer display the days of the month.